# How to show image from the oracle database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, oracle, webforms

Hi there i need to show an image stored in the oracle database in (blob format i think).i have retrieved the image from database in dataset  `= dt.rows[0]["image"]`.how can convert the image to show it on the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13365/Insert-retrieve-an-image-into-from-a-blob-field-in ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to display it on a page, you need to serve the image as a separate resource from the web server.

Meaning, your page.aspx will have a  tag with a src="your_image.aspx".  In your_image.aspx, you need to clear response headers, make sure the Content-type is set correctly (image/jpg or something similar), put the contents of dt.rows[0]["image"] into a byte array and then write it out the binary image with something like Response.BinaryWrite(yourByteArray).

This is just a general outline.  Use the googles for details :)